# Access token valid for one day only

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using server-side flow for authenticating users in my App. Most of the users are getting a 60-day valid token. However, recently there are few users whose tokens are valid only for 24 hours (Not 1 or 2hours which is the case with short-lived tokens).

Due to this problem users are stopping usage of the App as they have to authenticate every day in order to continue using it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There's no such token, that's validate for 1 day. Debug the issue carefully. And put some code here, do you really think we can help you just like that.

Comment: oh..Cant paste the relevant code here.. It's somewhat long.

Comment: Can you tell me your mail ID? I will mail you the code

Comment: You just have to paste the relevant code here. Its better to share here.

Comment: if (expiresExp.IsMatch(accessToken))
{
expiryInSeconds = Int32.Parse(expiresExp.Match(accessToken).Value.Replace("expires=", string.Empty));
if (expiryInSeconds > 0)
{
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, expiryInSeconds);
fbToken.ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.Add(ts);
}
}

Comment: This is the code which I use to get the expiry time from the FB response for 'oauth/access_token' API call

Comment: I have the same problem with a Desktop applications. Get 60 days access token except for this one user who gets 24-hour ones. Don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Many users have reported same problem: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/163942813778219